# Consultas de fechas por meses en SQL

Tags: sql-server

Como podría hacer para que me muestre la fecha de 4 meses después como por ejemplo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

después de haber asignado el mes 1 osea enero en la condición.

Esta es mi consulta

```
    SELECT Nombre, FechaVencimiento
    From Evaluado
    WHERE MONTH(FechaVencimiento)= 1
```

Espero que por favor me puedan ayudar.

Comment: Tenes muchas preguntas sin respuesta aceptada. Por favor, vuelve a revisar el [tour] para que sepas como funcionamos... Recorda no solo agradecer las respuestas, si no aceptarlas cuando resuelven  el problema. Respecto a esta pregunta, no se entiende bien que queres hacer. Donde queres digitar una fecha? que tiene que ver sql server en esto?

Comment: Ya especifique mejor la pregunta y si tiene que ver con SQL.

Comment: Sigue sin entenderse.. porque no le sumas 3 al mes??

Comment: es como que tome el mes actual y me muestre todas las fechas después de 3 meses.

Comment: pero le podes sumar 3 en todos lados.. en que lugar no pudiste hacerlo?

Comment: No se entiende lo que pides. Por favor se claro en tu pregunta. Detalla que quieres hacer, que problema te ha dado y donde te atascaste.

Comment: ` SELECT Nombre, FechaVencimiento From Evaluado MONTH(FechaVencimiento)= 1` aquí solo estoy tomando el mes actual si?, ahora no se como hacer que me muestre las fechas despues de tres meses osea que me muestre todas las fechas del mes de abril. de esta manera -> 2019-04-20

Comment: Si 1 corresponde a Enero quizas 4 corresponda a Abril ....

Comment: Quiero hacer algo así: SELECT Nombre, DATEADD(month, 3, FechaVencimiento) AS DateAdd
From Evaluado
WHERE MONTH(FechaVencimiento)= 1 pero hay lo esta haciendo algo mal.

Comment: Si quieres los registros de Abril WHERE MONTH(FechaVencimiento)= 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A ver, como primer consejo, no conviene usar funciones sobre la columna a la que quieres aplicar un filtro, porque si esa columna tenía algún índice, no lo vas a poder usar.

Como segundo consejo, cuando estás usando fechas, siempre es mejor al menos hablar de "año-mes", porque filtrando solo por fechas "mayores" al mes de "Enero", pueden aparecer datos de "Diciembre", pero del año pasado.

En fin, una alternativa es la siguiente:

```
DECLARE @Fecha date;
SET @Fecha = '20190101';

SELECT *
FROM dbo.Evaluado
WHERE FechaVencimiento >= DATEADD(MONTH,3,@Fecha)
;
```

Comment: Con esa consulta no me muestra solo las del mes 4 si no que me esta mostrando de casi todos los meses.

Comment: @AngieAroca bueno, claro, ya que pusiste en un comentario que quieres `es como que tome el mes actual y me muestre todas las fechas después de 3 meses`